# How to get first non-zero digit of a BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In java how do I get the first non-zero digit of a BigDecimal?

For example:

```
0.001 => 1
0.02 => 2
987.654 => 9
```

For numbers between 0 and 1 this will work:

```
bigDecimal.scaleByPowerOfTen(bigDecimal.precision()).setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN)
```

For numbers bigger than 1 this will work:

```
bigDecimal.scaleByPowerOfTen(1-bigDecimal.precision()).setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN)
```

But is there a solution, that works for any number?

Comment: Maybe take `bigDecimal.toPlainString()` and find the first thing that isn't a zero or dot.

Comment: how about putting it in a string, replacing all 0s and . with nothing, and dumping out the first char?

Comment: @LucasRoss I would also have to take care of "-" sign, etc. And converting to string seems much like a "workaround", not like a "solution"...

Comment: @slartidan As soon as you start talking about "first digit" of a number you are, in fact, talking about a representation in digits of a certain base - i.e., characters or string. As such, a number doesn't have a "first digit". So, using a conversion to string isn't really a "workaround".

Comment: I've written an answer that doesn't need to convert your BigDecimal to String or char array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using just `BigDecimal` and `int`:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(0.021); //input your value here

int scale = value.scale();
int precision = value.precision();
int result = value.movePointLeft(precision-scale-1).abs().intValue(); //this will generate the result you need
```

Comment: Just throw in a Math.abs at the end.

Comment: @laune Thank you for pointing that out! The BigDecimal already has an `abs()` method that I've added.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to convert `BigDecimal` into `char[]` and check for numbers using a loop. Look at following example.

```
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(5220.33);

    char[] chars = String.valueOf(bigDecimal).toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c) ? Character.getNumericValue(c) != 0 : false) {
            System.out.println("First number is : " + c);
            return;
        }
    }
```